# External HDD hangs

Tags: windows, freeze

One of my external HDDs will hang every 2-3 days.  I can drill down to the top level directories and see them on the external HDD ,but can drill down no further.

It's one of these external drive readers:

[image]

It is a dual 2.5 HDD reader with one 2Tb disk and one 400Mb disk inserted.

Here is what I have done:

1. power on/off HDD reader
2. unplug HDD reader
3. turn off express VPN (which sometimes gives me trouble)
4. scan for viruses
5. only thing left to is restart

After this occurs and I restart it hangs.  When I restart I get this screen:
[image]

It will **never** restart so I must power off by hand.

What else can I troubleshoot?

[image]

Comment: since you have been unmounting improperly (either by unpowering the enclosure or by hard shutdown) you likely have some degree of filesystem damage. check the SMART stats on the disk and run a full filesystem check (using chkdsk). it may be doing the same damage to your internal HDDs so I'd definitely start looking into why you can't restart gracefully.

Comment: Is your Windows OS or any software installed on any of those disks? Can you troubleshoot down to which disk is causing the issue by having only one at a time?

Answer (score 0):

> I can drill down to the top level directories and see them on the
> external HDD ,but can drill down no further.

Potentially the typical signs of a drive starting to fail. I am no fan of in-place repair tools, chkdsk being one of those but I can not stop you. These tools potentially makes things worse, irreversibly. Other tools I see recommended often, SpinRite and TestDisk, again I am not a fan in this type of situation.

Maybe worth a small risk: try a different USB adapter or attach the drive directly and see if that resolves the problem, up to you.

- You can check SMART, just look at values do not start any tests.
- Depending on what you see decide if it's safe to continue using a DIY approach.

Tell tale signs the drive is starting to fail are non zero RAW values for reallocated and pending sectors. If non zero values then decide if the data is worth sending to a data recovery lab. At this point you're probably looking at a $300-ish recovery.

If you decide to DIY:

- Ideally attach the drive using it's native interface, so SATA to SATA. Avoid USB if you can. USB is very bad at handling anomalies such as bad sectors.
- Clone (or image) the drive using ddrescue or HDDSuperClone, both free and open source tools.
- Small chance you can mount the clone or image file and access your data without additional tools. Otherwise use a file recovery tool to extract the data and save it. A tool like DMDE is probably all you need, costs $20.

If you get stuck then places like the HDDGuru.com forums and reddit.com/r/datarecovery are good places to ask.